# Round to minimum of 2 decimals and max of 4 decimals in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, rounding

Is there a way to round number to min 2 decimals i javascript.

Example:

1. 10 -> 10.00
2. 20.10 -> 20.10
3. 30.1234 -> 30.1234
4. 40.123456 -> 40.1235
5. 50.1200 -> 50.12
6. 60.123 -> 60.123

And so on... so round to min 2 decimals. I can use jquery for this.

Comment: What's the rule to round `40.123456` as `40.1235`? (`10` to `10.00` is not even rounding.)

Comment: Sorry, The point is to round to min 2 decimals (if there are no decimals it would be like formating the number) and to max of 4 decimals.

Comment: So what determines that `40.123456` becomes `"40.1235"` but `10` is `"10.00"` (and not `"10.000"` or `"10.0000"`)? And would `123.456` be `"123.456"` or `"123.46"` or `"123.4560"`? (I'm using quotes because we *are* talking about presentation here, right? Not numeric value?)

Comment: Rounding is not the problem here, the number of decimals are my issue sorry if I was not clear. @T.J.Crowder

Comment: 123.456 -> 123.456 @T.J.Crowder

Comment: Thanks for asking this question. Sometimes it's difficult to formulate it, but somehow you managed to get your answer (which is the most important). I had same issue, and found the answer thanks to your quesion. I voted it up. Was -2 but now it is -1.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It *sounds* like you're saying you want to turn numbers into strings with at least two decimal places (even if they're zeros) and up to four if necessary (they aren't zeros). If so:

For all modern browsers: [See Marek's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40850582/157247).

If you can't rely on `Intl`: The only thing I can think of is to use `toFixed(4)` and then remove up to two trailing zeros:

```js
function format(num) {
  var str = num.toFixed(4);
  return str.replace(/0{1,2}$/, '');
}
function test(test) {
  var result = format(test.num);
  console.log(
    test.num,
    "=>",
    result,
    result == test.result ? "- Pass" : "- Fail"
  );
}

[
    {num: 10, result:  "10.00"},
    {num: 20.10, result:  "20.10"},
    {num: 30.1234, result:  "30.1234"},
    {num: 40.123456, result:  "40.1235"},
    {num: 50.1200, result:  "50.12"},
    {num: 60.123, result:  "60.123"}
].forEach(test);
```

Comment: Thanks for the prompt response! I will test it right away.

Comment: That is what I needed I just replaced num.toFixed(4) with more precise rounding: 
'var roundedNum = +(Math.round(num + "e+4") + "e-4");
 var numTo4 = roundedNum.toFixed(4);'

Comment: And It was not that bad question after all?

Comment: I think using replace with regEx looks better :)
`str.replace(/0{1,2}$/,'')`

Comment: @Saram: I think so too, nice one. I'll edit that in. (Sadly I've reached my vote limit for the day, can't upvote your comment.)

Answer (score 6):

If you are not restricted to outdated browsers I recommend this smart feature:

```js
var fmtr = new Intl.NumberFormat('us-us', {
  style: 'decimal',
  useGrouping: false,
  minimumFractionDigits: 2,
  maximumFractionDigits: 4
});

function test(test) {
  var result = fmtr.format(test.num);
  console.log(
    test.num,
    "=>",
    result,
    result == test.result ? "- Pass" : "- Fail"
  );
}

[
    {num: 10, result:  "10.00"},
    {num: 20.10, result:  "20.10"},
    {num: 30.1234, result:  "30.1234"},
    {num: 40.123456, result:  "40.1235"},
    {num: 50.1200, result:  "50.12"},
    {num: 60.123, result:  "60.123"}
].forEach(test);
```

References:

- [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/NumberFormat)
- [Support Status on caniuse](http://caniuse.com/#feat=internationalization)
- Specification: [Current](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-402/2.0/#sec-11.1) | [Next Draft](https://tc39.github.io/ecma402/#numberformat-objects)

Comment: For me the best answer here!

Comment: Niiiiiiiiiiice. I knew about the 402 standard, and yet, didn't realize it did *this*. Fantastic.

Comment: I like this answer but the requirement is IE8+

Comment: @MarekSzczepansky: Always nice to support good answers from new people. Welcome to SO!

Comment: Funny... It fails in my Firefox/50 and Chrome/54 browsers (win64) because they ignore "us-us" and insert local decimal separator (`,`), but Microsoft browsers (IE/11 and Edge/38) run flawlessly.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure if case is important, maybe `us-US` will work.

Comment: @MarekSzczepansky Tried that, didn't work either. These kind of issues tend to come from missing or incomplete databases (for instance, Node.js does not bundle locale data because it's huge) but I  honestly don't know how browsers do it.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the toFixed() javascript function: [here](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_tofixed.asp)

It leaves it as a string though which may cause a problem depending on what you're doing

Comment: If the string return is a problem, you can always wrap it in a parseFloat.

Comment: String is not the problem, parseFloat is used Thanks for the suggestion

Answer (score 0):

The chosen solution only works for 4 decimals. Not 5 or more. If you are restricted to outdated browsers, the robust code below removes all trailing zeros and then adds 2 zeros if none left.

```
function format(n) {

  let r = (+n).toFixed(10); // or any

  if (r.match(/\./)) {
      r = r.replace(/\.?0+$/, '');
  }

  const s = r.toString();

  if (s.indexOf('.') === -1) {
      r = Number.parseFloat(r).toFixed(2);
  }

  return r;
}
```

I needed something like this but that could work with any amount of decimals and not restricted to outdated browsers.

This is one of the possible solutions not yet presented, which I posted with the hope someone could comment how to simplify this to regex only. Thanks!